# How to remove placeholder in textbox and note for email address shown in Checkout Page;Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to remove my placeholder in textbox as well as note for email address under Shipping address block.Can you please guide me.Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: that does not look like a place holder. Also email field does not have placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can override this file

**\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\form\element\email.html**

in your theme folder and remove below or comment below line:

```
 <span class="note" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible() == false">
```

after overriding please run following command:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>    php bin/magento  cache:flush

*and clear your browser cache and cookie and check*